# How can I get turtle id (myself who) Inside the ask turtle context?

Tags: design-patterns, netlogo

I just started using NetLogo and I'm trying to transition away from OOP, so I apologize if my coding paradigm is the source of my issue.

## Problem

Inside an `ask turtle` procedure I want each turtle to call a method passing itself to it as a parameter. I get en error: `Expected a number rather than a list or block`.

#### Attempts to solve the problem

```
ask turtles [
    setxy ( mean [pxcor] of my-territory ) ( mean [pycor] of my-territory )
    show my-territory
    report-status-and-split turtle [[who] of myself]
]
```

and i'm using it as:

```
report-status-and-split [reporting-turtle]
  ...
  create-turtles 1 [
    set color red
    if reporting-turtle != nobody
      [ create-link-with reporting-turtle [ set color green ]
        move-to reporting-turtle
        fd 8
      ]
   ]
```

I have also tried: `report-status-and-split [who myself]` and `report-status-and-split [myself [who]]`. All have an error of  `Expected a literal`.

So instead of using `who`, if I try to just pass `myself` as a parameter I get:

> You can't use REPORT-STATUS-AND-SPLIT in a turtle context, because REPORT-STATUS-AND-SPLIT is observer-only.

I'm sure my issue is simple.

**How can I properly use `who` with turles inside the ask-turtle context?**

Or **how can rethink my approach to follow Netlogo's coding practices?**

Comment: As a general rule, you almost never need `who` when coding NetLogo. If you're finding that you want to use it, you've probably not mastered the concepts of agentsets and context, both of which are really important. Try thinking from the perspective of "I am the turtle" (inside an `ask turtles` block), what do I do? You are thinking from the perspective of the observer, "I am external to the model", how do I tell the model what to do?

Comment: That is really helpful to keep in mind. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Change `report-status-and-split turtle [[who] of myself]` to `report-status-and-split self`.